# Why is the outer container div shrinking beyond its child element when resizing browser height?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So i have the following html page:

[image]

and I'm working on a "holy grail layout" using the grid structure in css for my website, consisting of a **header, and three divs side by side** occupying the **viewport** (full height) of the browser.

In the **first div**, i have **three textbox**.

However, I notice that when i **shrink the height of the browser**, the following happens:

[image]

The **outer grid container** which has the **orange border** seemed to **continue to shrink beyond the child div**. Why is this happening? How do i ensure that it follows the height of its child div and not continue shrinking?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header"
        "usr1 usr2 usr3";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

header {
    height: 3em;
    grid-area: header;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.userinput {
    grid-area: usr1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="text"] {
    min-height: 30vh;
}

.userinput2 {
    grid-area: usr2;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.userinput3 {
    grid-area: usr3;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="userinput">
      <div class="textbox1">
        <input type = "text" id="txt1" placeholder = "this is textbox 1">
      </div>
      <div class="textbox2">
        <input type = "text" id="txt2" placeholder = "this is textbox 2">
      </div>
      <div class="textbox3">
        <input type = "text" id="txt3" placeholder = "this is textbox 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="userinput2"></div>
    <div class="userinput3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `min-height` instead of `height` for `.container`. Or you can just not set its height and let it figure it out based on its content.

Comment: @Ouroborus thank you! I could just let the height be auto but i needed the container to occupy the full height of the viewport regardless of its content.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto` to the `.container`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header"
        "usr1 usr2 usr3";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

header {
    height: 3em;
    grid-area: header;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.userinput {
    grid-area: usr1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="text"] {
    min-height: 30vh;
}

.userinput2 {
    grid-area: usr2;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.userinput3 {
    grid-area: usr3;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="userinput">
      <div class="textbox1">
        <input type = "text" id="txt1" placeholder = "this is textbox 1">
      </div>
      <div class="textbox2">
        <input type = "text" id="txt2" placeholder = "this is textbox 2">
      </div>
      <div class="textbox3">
        <input type = "text" id="txt3" placeholder = "this is textbox 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="userinput2"></div>
    <div class="userinput3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```